# Unable connecting to a third party server after adding SSL on a subdomain

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, networking, server, devops

I get the following error while calling a third-party without any change in the code, I mean, the third-party calling was working well until few hours ago

> `{"status":0,"content":"cURL error 7: Failed to connect to saheam.ir port 443: Connection timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"}`

Noted that, I just was playing with "certbot" to renew a ssl for a subdomain, and I don't know why the third-party api calling got broken.

any clue how can I fix the issue?

---

It's actually a remove server issue, but the problem happened exactly when I was playing with the generating a new ssl for a subdomain. Also, since in the error it's mentioned port 443 (Failed to connect to saheam.ir port 443), I guess there is a relevance between the issue and the recent generated certificate